# How to hide MKAnnotationView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, mkmapview, mkannotationview

I have a problem hiding a `MKAnnotationView` after some time [4 seconds]. I have a `MKMapView` named **mapView** which shows user location with `MKUserLocation` and I have added a `UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure` to his `MKAnnotationView`. The `MKAnnotationView` automatically gets selected but I want to deselect it after some time with a `NSTimer`. I have correctly implemented the timer and the void method gets called correctly [I have checked it with a `NSLog`] but I don't know what code to write in the void method to make the annotation disappear.

this is my code:

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didAddAnnotationViews:(NSArray *)views
{
    for (MKAnnotationView* view in views)
    {
        if ([view.annotation isKindOfClass:[MKUserLocation class]])
        {
            view.rightCalloutAccessoryView = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];

            [self.mapView selectAnnotation:view.annotation animated:YES];
        }

        mKAnnotationHideTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:4.0
                                                                 target:self
                                                               selector:@selector(hideMKAnnotation:)
                                                               userInfo:nil
                                                                repeats:NO];
    }
}

- (void)hideMKAnnotation:(NSArray *)views
{
   // What code here?
}
```

Can someone help me writing the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass your view.annotation as userInfo object and implement hideMKAnnotation as

```
- (void)hideMKAnnotation:(NSTimer*)timer
{ 
     id aview = timer.userInfo;
     [self.mapView deselectAnnotation:aview animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick answer @malex, that worked :-). But now XCode gives me a yellow warning which says: "Sending 'MKAnnotationView *__strong' to parameter of incompatible type 'id<MKAnnotation>' " how can I fix this?

Comment: Nevermind, I've fixed it adding "(id)" to "aview" so now it's "deselectAnnotation:(id)aview"

Comment: I forgot that deselectAnnotation: has id argument. I've corrected my answer. Thanks.